# const literal versus const function as rvalue?

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

I have a big confusion about how a c++ compiler treating with a const variable

```
const int constfunc()
{
   return 7;
}
const int u1 = constfunc();
int* pu1 = const_cast<int*>(&u1);
*pu1 = 10;
cout << u1 << endl;
cout << *pu1 <<endl;
```

The result of precending code is:
10
10

While I try to assign a literal value to u1 variable neither than a const function, I mean:

```
const int u1 = 7;
```

The result will be changed:
7
10

I have really two confusions:
1- I made a little change but the result different?
2- As I know a const_cast remove a const restriction on a const pointers which point to none const variables, but in my sample1 I can modify value of const variable "u1"?

Comment: `*pu2 = 10;` is an attempt to modify const object `u1` and causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Casting away const from something that was not originally declared non-const and assigning to it results in Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This confusion is related to a compiler's optimization, i.e:

```
const int u1 = 7;
```

This tell compiler the u1 variable can't be change and can be evaluated at compile time, so you can replace each u1 in the code by it's value (7), i.e printing code will be modified by the compiler as:

```
cout << 7 << endl;
```

When you call an address of the u1 variable:

```
int* pu1 = const_cast<int*>(&u1);
```

The compiler will automatically create a storage for const variable and put it's info in a symbol table, so the result is 7 10.

Another case, when you write:

```
const int constfunc()
{
   return 7;
}
const int u1 = constfunc();
```

This tells the compiler the u1 variable can't be change and u1 will be evaluated at runtime time neither than compile time, because it's rvalue is result of the constfunc execution, so no optimization here and the u1 variable will allocate a memory storage and printing u1 code will still as it to fetch its value from a memory:

```
cout << u1 << endl;
```

Note1: Put constexpr specifier to the constfunc function will enforce the compiler to evaluate the u1 variable at compile time neither run time so the result will be changed as 7 10.

Note2: Removing const restriction by const_cast may be *undefined behavior*

Comment: These are observations on your platform and your compiler. It's not guaranteed to be the same on other machines.

Comment: @super yes this what I mean in Note2.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* pu1 = const_cast<int*>(&u1);
```

removes the `const` restriction.

```
*pu1 = 10;
```

calls for *undefined behavior*.

Thus the result of

```
cout << u1 << endl;
cout << *pu1 <<endl;
```

won't be predictable by the means of c++ standards.

---

Here's a lil' illustration how it goes:

[image]

So just write clean code and don't try to undermine compiler errors using *cast* expressions, unless you're a 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: @BassamNajeeb It's still UB. No reasonable answer regarding the behavior can be given. I was able to extrapolate that typo, you had in your original question.

Comment: @BassamNajeeb _"Can you give a useful example to const_cast?"_ No, I can't, unless you're giving me an absolute waterproof use case why you would need that, and the behavior is predictable with your actual toolchain and environment.

Comment: @BassamNajeeb Something like doing a workaround for a flaw or error that something was declared `const` in an API you are using, while that shouldn't or isn't actually `const` for good reasons.